# String concatenation - Boolean hard-coded Vs Boolean Concatenation with String

Tags: java, .net, jvm, clr

I need a advice (both in java & .net) for the following piece of code.

```
 public void method(bool value)
 {
     String someString;

     //some code

     if (value)
     {
          //some code
          ...
         someString = "one" + value;              
     }
     else
     {
         //some code
         ...
         someString = "two" + value;
     }

 }
```

Which one is advisable and why? either code like above or code like

```
someString = "onetrue";
someString = "twofalse";
```

Comment: Seems like a fair coding question.

Comment: I am expecting more in a way like String concatenation, string immutable, new string object creation and performance.

Comment: Unless you give us some context the only thing we can go on is the example you've posted. We can't read your mind. If you're interested in specifics please give specifics and the use cases you have in mind and the code you're considering/have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After compilation and optimization by JDK, `method` will look like:

```
public static String method(boolean value) {
    String someString;

    if (value) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("one");
        sb.append(value);
        someString = sb.toString();
    } else {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("two");
        sb.append(value);
        someString = sb.toString();
    }
    return someString;
}
```

If this code is invoked very frequently, it could bring a performance impact, compared to the second version. In each case a new StringBuilder is constructed and three methods are invoked on it. And boolean should be converted to an object before calling `append`.  While in the second version we just return constant. Everything depends on how often this code is called.

Answer (score 0):

Neither will make any difference it's purely style.

Since you have `// some other code` I'd just stick with the first. If you only had one line in each branch  then either is ok.

Answer (score 0):

At a high level they both are the same but if you look down at lower levels, I would advise to using the method:

```
someString = "onetrue";

someString = "twofalse";
```

This is because when you do "one" + value, the value is actually a bool and the `toString()` method of the bool object  will be called to add to the string. Basically just adding another step opposed to just specifying what to add to the string.